# Deployment Workbench and Windows Updates

Tags: windows-update, wds, deployment

We use Windows Deployment services and the deployment workbench to build our standard machines with, this obviously speeds up the deployment process but we are finding every 3 months or so we have to create a new image that contains the latest windows update patches, otherwise the fresh machine can take an hour or so to download/install/reboot new patches.

Is it possible to automatically upload the new patches into the images somehow? I could probably packages them up and have a post install process, but this kind of doing what it is now. Ideally I’d like to be able to slipstream any critical/security patches into the image as they become available without having to think about it

Cheers
Luke

Comment: There's no need to install, update, recapture just for Windows Updates. See my answer in the question linked above.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to [service an offline image](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799304(v=ws.10).aspx) using the Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool (DISM). DISM is part of the [Windows Automated Installation Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5753)(WAIK) or the new [Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652) (WADK - which replaces WAIK for Windows 8).

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323166) will help you find and download the update packages.

You should always make a copy of the image first, just in case.

Then you mount the image, apply the packages and commit changes:

```
MD C:\MyDir\Mount
DISM /Mount-Wim /WimFile:E:\images\myimage.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\MyDir\Mount

DISM /image:C:\MyDir\Mount /Add-Package /Packagepath:<file_path>

DISM /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\MyDir\Mount /Commit
```

If there are a lot of updates, you can use PowerShell and DISM together to script the installs. 
[This TechNet blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrdogs/archive/2012/02/15/applying-windows-updates-to-a-base-wim-using-dism-and-powershell.aspx) post from the ConfigMgrDogs blog will help.

More articles and videos to help with MDT can be found on the [Deliver and Deploy Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dd641427.aspx) page and the [Deliver and Deploy Windows 8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh974336) page of the Springboard Series on TechNet.

Hope this helps,

Comment: sounds good, i'll have a look into it